# "NoClassDefFoundError" from android library

Tags: android

I have developed QR scanner library using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4' library and pulished to maven and implementing that QR Scanner Library in new app where i've calling activity from QR Scanner library. At the runtime of that application app getting crashed.

**Here is the logs**

```java
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aceapp, PID: 10555
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/BarcodeDetector$Builder;
        at com.a8.qrcodereader.QrCodeScannerActivity.createCameraSource(QrCodeScannerActivity.java:96)
        at com.a8.qrcodereader.QrCodeScannerActivity.onCreate(QrCodeScannerActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
```

**What works for me:**

if i implement 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4' to app its working fine.

**Is that necessary to add library(vision:11) in both app and sdk(qrscanner)

Comment: If it is an aar file and locally added to your project then yes you have add the dependancy in both.

Comment: without 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4 it work fine but if you don't put scanner library then it will show error